# express get root event does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, url-routing

When I request *localhost:8080/chat?k=1&d=1* it writes "CHAT PAGE" to console and works correctly. But when I tried to get *localhost:8080* root event does not write "INDEX PAGE" and it automatically gets index.html even though I set index to false. Here is my code;

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var encData;
var appointmentKey;
var urlGetDataAreValid = false;

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static'), { index: false }));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("INDEX PAGE");
    res.sendFile('static/error.html');
});

app.get('/chat', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("CHAT PAGE");
    encData = req.param('d');
    appointmentKey = req.param('k');

    if ((encData === undefined || encData === null) || (appointmentKey === undefined || appointmentKey === null) ) {
        res.sendfile('static/error.html');
    }
    else {
        urlGetDataAreValid = true;
        res.sendfile('static/index.html');
    }
});

var server = app.listen('8080');
```

Comment: Your code is working for me, however it shows an error at `res.sendFile` in line 14: `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

Comment: You should use `req.params.d` and `req.params.k` instead of `req.param('d')` and `req.param('k')`. `res.sendfile` is deprecated, you should use `res.sendFile`.

Comment: @maxkl It does not give error to me. It only shows "index.html".

Comment: Which version of express are you using?

Comment: `"version": "4.13.3"`

Comment: Is this your full code? And are you sure your browser does not automatically complete the URL to localhost:8080/index.html?

Comment: It returns 200 OK. Does not redirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85452/discussion-between-maxkl-and-cem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of express seems to be outdated. You have to update it to the latest version. Execute this command in your console:

```
npm install express@latest
```

You also have to change `res.sendfile("static/error.html")` to `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "static/error.html"))` and `req.param("d")` to `req.params.d`.